# Python reads 20 records in a loop through islice

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am reading a TXT file (1GB). The content is a lot of URL records. I want to call a function to return 20 records. How can the code be modified to allow him to return the remaining N records each time? which makes me confused.

```
from itertools import islice

def iter_list(start，stop):
    url = []
    with open("domain.txt") as file:
        for line in islice(file, start, stop):
            url.append(line)
        return url
```

```html
def get_html(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    print(req.status_code)
"""
     I want to extract 20 pieces to process after the cycle is completed. I don't know if this expression can be       understood. 
"""
url = iter_list(1, 20)
for i in url:
    get_html(i.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice

def iter_list(start，stop):
    url = []
    tmp = []
    with open("domain.txt") as file:
        for line in islice(file, start, stop):
            url.append(line)
            if len(url) == 20:
               url.append(tmp)
               tmp = []
        return url


for i in iter_list(start，stop):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Maybe my description is not good.The first call returns a record from 1 to 20, the second call from 20 to 40, and the third call from 40 to 60, which is what I need.

Comment: I editted my answer now. The method returns a list consist of lists which hold 20 row. Does it work for you?

Comment: def get_html(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    print(req.status_code)
"""
I hope that after the loop is complete, I will extract 20 more pieces for processing until the document is processed. I don't know if this expression can be understood?
"""
url = iter_list(1, 20)
for i in url:
    get_html(i.strip())

Comment: Its hard to understand on comment line but probably it will work.

Comment: It may not be very clear, sorry, Return 20 pieces at a time by iter_list(), and give it to get_html(). After the processing is completed, extract 20 pieces again, until the last line of the file.